# How to use the Wordpress for free with complete features

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

As i am working on this wordpress platform from past 1+ year, i was looking out to spread this knowledge of building a website through wordpress, for around 100 students.

How can I provide free solution with complete features of WordPress rather than free version

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I provide free solution with complete features of WordPress rather than free version

You pay for 100 WordPress accounts with complete features and gives accounts to your students for free.